# Why is this MySQL Select query returning an error, but completing the Select perfectly fine?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this PHP with a MySQL SELECT:

```
$q = "SELECT signup_id, email 
        FROM signups 
       LIMIT ". $inNum;
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) >= 1) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
```

I am not sure why I am receiving this error because the code is running perfectly fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does it show if you `print($r);`? `mysqli_query` returns `FALSE` on failure so I'm betting you're getting an error. Maybe because the query doesn't end in a semicolon.

Comment: Actually get rid of the "or trigger_error()" bit - I bet it's evaluating the logical result of (mysqli_query or trigger_error) as a boolean.

Comment: @evan I tried and it didn't change anything.

Comment: @evan I tried printing it and it send an error on that line of `Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string`

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're setting the value of `$r` up to be a boolean with the `or`, and so an array of results is being processed AND an error is thrown because `$r` looks like it's only ever going to be a boolean value. I could be wrong, but it looks like confusing logic to start with.

Answer (score 1):

[mysqli_affected_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

> Returns the number of rows affected by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query.

Change to mysqli_num_rows and pass the query result:

```
$q = "SELECT signup_id, email FROM signups LIMIT ".$inNum;
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

if (mysqli_num_rows($r) >= 1) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Both Matt and Tony sound like good answers if they were put together.

```
 if ($r = mysqli_query( ... )) {
      if (mysql_num_rows($r) >= 1) {
           while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r, ..) { 
                 ...
           } 
      }
 }
```